# Laravel - Square divs

Tags: html, laravel, bootstrap-4, square

I'd need to make square div's containing an image. The difficulty I am having, is that I would like it to be square, without having to give it a size. it should be squared in proportion to the max width it gets from the parent div, being limited in this case to col-3. All the samples I was able to find here, do not answer my question.

```
 <div class="col-3 pb-3">
            <div > <<<<<<<<<----------- THIS ONE SHOULD BE SQUARE
                <img src="/images/{{$photo->filename}}" style="
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
                object-fit: scale-down;">
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary mb-0" type="button">
                Remove
            </button>
        </div>
```

How can this be done?

Comment: You must set height for any of the parents that will be the height of the square image. Be it col-3 or the parent of col-3.

Comment: @Eliasu but i do not know the size, since col-3 is dependent from the width of the page...

Comment: Ok then the height of the page can be calculated as calc( 100vw  / 3), assuming there are 3 columns in a row. If there are margins do subtract it from 100vw before the division.